# Can I use an emphatic "did" in the passive past tense?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

Can I use the emphatic *did* in the past passive, or is it only for the active tense? For example:

> "The Romans *did* build the bridges!" (active voice)

How would I say that in the passive voice?

I was thinking:

> "The bridges *did* used to be built by the Romans!" (passive? with emphatic *did*? I am not sure)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me walk you through it.

What bridges? Certain specific bridges? Or all the bridges we know of? Hmm. Okay, we do know know that the Romans built *some* bridges. They had the know-how, and their engineering was top-notch.

Now let's imagine we're standing on a riverbank, taking in the sights. We can see two bridges of unmistakably Roman design. Someone standing beside us questions Roman engineering.

Our response is:

> The Romans did build those bridges.

Now let's change the scenario a little bit. Suppose that instead of having doubts about Roman ingenuity our companion should question the Roman's willingness to use it too far from home (we're in Germany right now). He or she says that while, say, Rome and Florence are awash with Roman stuff, very little of it can be found north of the Alps. Now it's time for you to point at the bridges and say:

> Those bridges did get built by the Romans.

So, I guess, the trick is to introduce the word "get" somewhere in there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. Use of "get" makes all the difference. +1

Answer (score 2):

You would emphasize a form of the verb *be*, such as:

> The bridges *were* built by the Romans!

Alternatively, you could insert another word for emphasis, such as:

> The bridges were *indeed* built by the Romans!

As far as I can tell, *did* is only ever used in the active voice.